# replace weblogic 12 internal hibernate-validator

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic

WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0

using weblogic internal hibernate-validator is work good.

but for some reason, we want to use hibernate-validator provide by jar to replace interal one.

I have try the way in
[Weblogic has old version of Bean Validator](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/weblogic-has-old-version-of-bean-validator/2498) and add something into weblogic.xml

but finally got an exception when call to any API

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

full weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>awesome-api</context-root>

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.apache.commons.logging.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>

        <prefer-application-resources>
            <resource-name>org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class</resource-name>
        </prefer-application-resources>
    </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

here the error detail

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.validation.Validator field org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validator to org.jboss.weld.proxies.ExecutableValidator$Validator$976505265$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94)
at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:378)
at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:389)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionServicesAdapter.aroundInject(WeldInjectionServicesAdapter.java:52)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldBeanManager.newInterceptorInstance(WeldBeanManager.java:159)
at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.InjectionBasedEjbComponentCreator.getBean(InjectionBasedEjbComponentCreator.java:108)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.createNewBeanInstance(BaseEJBManager.java:220)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.allocateBean(BaseEJBManager.java:246)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.StatelessManager.createBean(StatelessManager.java:268)
at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.StatelessSessionPool.createBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:132)
at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.StatelessSessionPool.getBean(StatelessSessionPool.java:99)
at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.StatelessManager.preInvoke(StatelessManager.java:153)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.getBeanInstance(BaseLocalObject.java:141)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.preInvoke(BaseLocalObject.java:103)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.__WL_preInvoke(BaseLocalObject.java:69)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:22)
at controller.OrderController_hx3ni8_NoIntfViewImpl.getOrderList(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3709)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3675)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2446)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2294)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2272)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1705)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1665)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Comment: Can you share the complete weblogic.xml file ?

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin weblogic.xml has updated in the post